# Passing value from Controller to view Page

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I want when i login, the value inside my model i.e.(userProfile) be passed from my controller to my view page so as to display or printout the email of the user.
Below is my View and Controller:

My View Page is:

```
<c:out value="${userprofile.email}" />
```

Controller is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String authenticateLogin(@Valid @ModelAttribute("loginAttribute") UserProfileForm userProfile,                                   HttpServletRequest request, 
Model model){


    if(userProfile.getEmail() !=null && userProfile.getPassword() !=null){
        if(userProfileBo.processLoginCredentials(userProfile.getEmail(), userProfile.getPassword())){
            model.addAttribute("userProfile", userProfile.getEmail());
            System.out.println("Email for username is: " + userProfile.getEmail());             
            return "redirect:/treepage";
        }
        else{
            return "redirect:/";
        }           

    }
    else{
            return "redirect:/";    
    }

}
```

The displayed result is this - `${userprofile.email}`

Answer (score 0):

I don't like MVC and have only done one project using it so my knowledge is limited. I think there is a ViewBag variable on the client side you can fill with values from the controller and access them from the view.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code has one mistake:
You set`userProfile` in your controller and use `userprofile` in your view.

Try to use `<c:out value="${userProfile.email}" />` in your view, and if problem not resolved, use something like this:

```
<h1>${userProfile.email}</h1>
```